# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5

When I am submitting a form it gives me an error,SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: insert into `clients` (`client_name`) values ())

Comment: … and none of the solutions you’d find on the web when searching for `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` work for you?

Comment: There’s this website called google.com. It has a large text input field. Enter your query into this form. Then hit the “search” button. You will then see a list of matching results.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently. I had a key in my `.env` file for my database host, which was initially set to the value `localhost`. Changing that to `127.0.0.1` fixed my issue.